# Как настроить файл .htpasswd и .htaccess для запуска проекта на openserver

Tags: php, openserver

Всем привет! У меня появилась проблема что я никогда не работал с проектом на php.
Теперь мне надо сделать некоторые правки на проекте. Мне прислали проект и я запустил его на open-server. Но оказывается там есть файл .htaccess который не дает мне запустить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне сказали что надо создать файл .htpasswd с логином и паролем онлайн. Я это сделал. А потом надо сделать алиас для /home/admin/web/.htpasswd .
Я создал файл и положил у себя по этому пути "C:\home\admin\web\.htpasswd"

После всего этого я опять перезапустил open-server и прописал логин и пароль и мне выскакивает вот эта страница снизу.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я поискал информацию по этому поводу в инете но подробной инструкции по этому не смог найти.
Подскажите пожалуйста что я сделал не так или что еще надо сделать что бы запустить этот проект. Спасибо!

Comment: Простите, но вопрос слишком общий и отсутствуют детали. По картинкам гадать никто не сможет.